# Matriz transpuesta en c++

Tags: c++

tengo mi código, pero no me da, lo que quiero hacer es este resultado.

```
[1][2]

[3][4]

[5][6]
```

a esto:

```
[1][3][5]

[2][4][6]
```

pero no me da, lo que quería hacer es pasar los datos del ciclo for de la matriz 1, a los datos de i digamos de la matriz 2, y después de la j, a la jota de la matriz 2, pero no me funciona, espero me puedan ayudar, saludos amigos de la comunidad.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    
    int a[3][2];
    int b[2][3];
    int aux=0;
    cout<<"Agrega los valores"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
            cin>>a[i][j];
     
        }
    }
    
    
    for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<2; y++){
            cout<<"["<<a[x][y]<<"]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    
    for(int p=0; p<3; p++){
        for(int q=0; q<2; q++){
            a[p][q]=b[p][q];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int h=0; h<2; h++){
        for(int n=0; n<3; n++){
            cout<<"["<<b[h][n]<<"]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola, bienvenido a SOes!

Cuando haces la transposición estás asignando mal los arrays por dos cosas:

1. `b` es tu array de salida, por lo tanto la asignación debería de ser hacía los elementos de `b`, algo cómo `b[x][y] = a[x][y]`. De lo contrario no tocas el array `b` y obtienes datos basura que habitan en el mismo.
2. Si `b` es de un tamaño 2x3 y `a` es de tamaño 3x2. Y en tus bucles `for` definiste que `p` llega hasta 3 y `q` hasta 2 entonces tienes que respetar eso a la hora de hacer la asignación, no puedes dejar las variables de iteración iguales porque sus tamaños sn diferentes, es decir, esto no está bien:  `a[p][q]=b[p][q];`.

Tomando estas dos cosas, la corrección que tienes que hacer en tu código sería cambiar:

```
a[p][q]=b[p][q];
```

Por:

```
b[q][p] = a[p][q];
```